# Would riding kick scooter wear out your shoes?

Tags: exercise

I've been thinking about getting a kickscooter (an adult one) and scootering from and to work for fitness and transportation. I need to go maybe 4-5km.

I'm just wondering, because you need to push with your leg, do the scooters wear out your shoes? Would they be suitable to wear work shoes with them? What are the best shoes for scootering?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about durable shoes. Just because you mention the word fitness doesn't mean it's fitness related.

Comment: I agree with @JohnP, although I'll add the clarifying point that it's not *directly* related to fitness, since nearly anything is "related" to fitness in the same way we're all related to Kevin Bacon.

Comment: a question about the most suitable shoes to wear for a specific fitness activity is not directly related to fitness? really?